# Palindrome Filter, the functions work perfectly, but the main() doesn't compile

Tags: c++, palindrome

The compiler gives me one error, I tried everything including a for cycle but it didn't help me, maybe someone has an idea?
The functions are perfectly working, but the main() part doesn't

```
#include <iostream>
#include<vector>

using namespace std;


bool IsPalindrom(string s) {
    for (size_t i = 0; i < s.size() / 2; ++i) {
        if (s[i] != s[s.size() - i - 1]) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}

vector <string> PalindromFilter(vector<string> words, int min_Length){
 vector<string> result;
 for(auto s : words){
    if (s.size() >= min_Length && IsPalindrom(s)){
        result.push_back(s);
    }
 }
 return result;

}

int main(){


cout << PalindromFilter({"abacaba", "aba"}, 4);
}
```

Comment: The compiler doesn't know how to interpret `cout`ing a vector on its own. Try looping over the strings in your vector and printing them instead.

Comment: ***The compiler gives me one error*** As a programmer you will have spend some time and learn how to read error messages. At minimum the compiler should have told you what line of what line of what file contained the error.

Comment: "The functions are perfectly working" -  I note that a compile error aborts the link ... so there is nothing to run.  Perhaps I am misunderstanding ... when you say  the "functions are perfectly working",  are you writing about the compile and link function? (i.e. g++ or make or something else?)

Answer (score 0):

Note the return type of the `PalindromFilter()` function. It returns a **vector of string**. You cannot directly print the contents of a vector using `cout`.

Instead you could try store the returned values and use a display function. Code for your reference:

```
// Function to display elements of the vector of strings
void Display(const vector<string> & vec)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < vec.size(); i++)
    {
        // Note that for printing a string you need to
        // use c_str() 
        cout << vec[i].c_str() << endl;
    }
}
```

In Main function:

```
int main() 
{
    vector<string> output = PalindromFilter({ "abacaba", "aba" }, 4);
    Display(output);
    return 0;
}
```